# Executing a command with execvp

Tags: c, execvp

I have an array of command strings I want to execute by calling `execvp()`:

```
char* commands[] = ["ls -l", "ps -a", "ps"];
char* command = commands[0];
...
```

How do I execute the command with `execvp`?

Comment: You must separate command and arguments into separate strings: `{"ls", "-l", NULL}`, and `fork()` and `execvp()` once for each command line you want to execute. You're missing a `NULL` pointer at the end. The last entry of the `char* commands[]` array must be a NULL pointer.

Comment: If you were to run the command from the command line, what would it look like?

Comment: if I were to run it from the command, line, it would just be "ls -l"

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible usage example for you. This takes the command to execute from its arguments or you can uncomment the hardcoded example.

I recommend you look up the used commands in their respective man pages.
For `execvp`, the declaration is

```
int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]);
```

`argv[0]` should be the same as `file` by convention and `argv` should be `NULL`-terminated.

```
#include <stdlib.h> //exit
#include <stdio.h>  //perror
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int pid, status, ret;
    if((pid=fork())<0) { perror("fork"); exit(EX_OSERR); }

    if(!pid){ //Child

    /*
        char* args[] = { "ps", "-a", (char*)0 };
        execvp(args[0], args);
    */

        //Execute arguments, already NULL terminated
        execvp(argv[1], argv+1);

    //exec doesn't exit; if it does, it's an error
        perror(argv[1]);

    //Convert exec failure to exit status, shell-style (optional)
        switch(errno){
            case EACCES: exit(126);
            case ENOENT: exit(127);
            default:         exit(1);
        }
    }

  //Wait on child
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

  //Return the same exit status as child did or convert a signal termination 
  //to status, shell-style (optional)

    ret = WEXITSTATUS(status);
    if (!WIFEXITED(status)) {
        ret += 128;
        ret = WSTOPSIG(status);
        if (!WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
            ret = WTERMSIG(status);
        }
    }
  return ret;
}
```